# Write characters in the font used in \section without using the command \section

Tags: fonts

I'm writing a `\documentclass{article}`

I really like the font used in the command `\section`

I write text using this command. Things like:

```
\section{Problem 1}
```

I want to know if there is a better way to use this font.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The file `article.cls` contains:

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

Therefore the font is

```
\normalfont\Large\bfseries
```

`\normalfont` is defined in `latex.ltx` (LaTeX kernel):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\normalfont
                 {\usefont\encodingdefault
                          \familydefault
                          \seriesdefault
                          \shapedefault
                  \relax}
```

The default settings (unless redefined, e.g. by a font package) are defined in `fonttext.ltx`, part of the LaTeX kernel:

```
\newcommand\rmdefault{cmr}
\newcommand\bfdefault{bx}
\newcommand\mddefault{m}
\newcommand\updefault{n}
\newcommand\encodingdefault{OT1}
\newcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}
\newcommand\seriesdefault{\mddefault}
\newcommand\shapedefault{\updefault}
```

`\bfseries` is defined in `latex.ltx`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\bfseries
    {\not@math@alphabet\bfseries\mathbf
     \fontseries\bfdefault\selectfont}
```

Thus the default font is **`OT1/cmr/bx/n`**, the size is `\Large`, the exact size depends on the class option `10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt`. The values for `\Large` can be found in the class option files `size10.clo`, `size11.clo`, `size12.clo`:

- Default option `10pt`: `\Large` = 14pt, `\baselineskip` = 18pt
- Option `11pt`: `\Large` = 14pt, `\baselineskip` = 18pt
- Option `12pt`: `\Large` = 17pt, `\baselineskip` = 22pt